# Configuring FreeNAS on Hardware RAID

Tags: raid, truenas

I have a server with 16 Gb RAM and 4x1TB HDDs configured as RAID 10. Now I have to configure that server for the FreeNAS, but I have found that the FreeNAS won't support the Hardware RAID.  Instead, it has the software RAID but the software RAID requires 5 HDDs.  One of them will be used for the OS and can't be used for other RAID configuration.  My server does not support 5 hard drives.

How can I FreeNAS with Hardware RAID 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a SATA dom or a small SSD for the OS. If you don't have a free SATA port you can also put the OS on 2 mirrored USB flash drives. Cheap USB flash drives fail more often and make for really slow system updates, so they are not a good fit for a server. But once the system is running performance is not affected. Don't place the OS on the disks intended for storage. If you don't want to use USB flash drives, then add another HBA for the SATA dom or OS SSD.

And make sure you don't use hardware RAID with FreeNAS.